# How to use sessions for JAX-WS web service in JAVA

Tags: java, session, soap, jax-ws

I have created a JAVA web service and a client application in netbeans. The client application connects to web service through normal WebMethods. I want to know how can I use sessions to connect to web service. Also please tell  is there a better approach to access web service from client application rather than just simply calling web methods for each request?

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is code example that shows, how to implement session in JAXWS



  /* server code */

    package com.foo.ws.session;
    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import  javax.jws.WebService;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
    import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;
    import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
    @WebServicepublic class Hello {

    //webServiceContext is injected by the JAXWS API
    @Resource private WebServiceContext wsContext;

    @WebMethod public int getCounter(){

           MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
          HttpSession session = (HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession();
          // Get a session property "counter" from context
          if (session == null)
              throw new WebServiceException("No session in WebServiceContext");
          Integer counter = (Integer)session.getAttribute("counter");
          if (counter == null) {
               counter = new Integer(0);
               System.out.println("Starting the Session");
          }
        counter = new Integer(counter.intValue() + 1);
        session.setAttribute("counter", counter);
        return counter;
      }
    }



/* client code*/

package com.foo.ws.session.client;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
public class ClientMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Hello proxy = new HelloService().getHelloPort();
      //setting requestContext so that session could be maintained through client and server
      Map requestContext = ((BindingProvider)proxy).getRequestContext();
      requestContext.put(BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY,true);
      int result = proxy.getCounter();
      System.out.println(result);
      result = proxy.getCounter();
      System.out.println(result);
}
}
```